# spring security 2 login form call one another without authenticating

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am writing a spring security code with 2 login forms and 2 login URLs. The problem is that when I pres on sign in button on any login form without even true authenticating it directs me to the other login form. When I try the other login form the same happens. If someone has any clue is welcome to comment.
My code is:

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfigurationAdmin extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        http
        .antMatcher("/adminlogin*")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
                "/login2",
                "/login",
                "/registration**",
                "/js/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/adminlogin*").hasRole("USER2")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login2").permitAll()
//            .loginProcessingUrl("/login22")
            .usernameParameter("username2")
            .passwordParameter("password2")
            .successForwardUrl("/adminlogin")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/adminlogin",true)
//            .failureUrl("/login2")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
            .permitAll();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("USER2");
    }
```

and :

```
@Order(2)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .antMatcher("/librarianlogin*")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
                "/login",
                "/login2",
                "/registration**",
                "/js/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/librarianlogin").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
//            .loginProcessingUrl("/login1")
            .successForwardUrl("/librarianlogin")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/librarianlogin",true)
//            .failureUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
            .permitAll();    
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

I m sure that everything that is missing is in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter classes since when I compile the code separately from the 2 log in forms they work perfectly. When i combine them together something goes wrong.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by the first couple of lines in each `HttpSecurity` configuration. Your code says `http.antMatcher` to begin, and what this does restricts that filter chian to only that path. For example `http.antMatcher("/foo/**")` means that filter chain should only pay attention to URIs starting with `/foo/`. Maybe simplifying it down to the simplest configuration that still reproduces the issue would help clarify.

Comment: @jzheaux thanks for the reply but I have tried your suggestion but didn't work. I have modeled the antMathcher this way so that I can make it work for one page and later on make the final modifications. I m not sure if the mistake is here?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your configuration, it appears that you want to have two separate user bases, one for administrators, and one for librarians. You are using different login pages in order to know which is which.

To do this, you need to have multiple filter chains, which is how you've already begun. I'd suggest some tweaks, though.

First, the top-level `antMatcher` call is for segmenting out your application. For example, it's common for all admin pages to be served under the `/admin` path. In that case, you can do:

```java
@Order(1)
@Configuration
public class AdminSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/admin/**")
            .authorizeRequests((authz) -> authz
                .mvcMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/admin/login").permitAll()
            );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService adminUsers = // ... construct
        auth.userDetailsService(adminUsers);
    }
}
```

for the admin's part of the site, and:

```java
@Order(2)
@Configuration
public LibrarianSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdatper {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService users = // ...
        auth.userDetailsService(adminUsers);
    }
}
```

for the librarian part.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Order matters. When you have multiple filter chains, Spring Security will pick the first chain whose matcher matches the request path. So, `/admin/**` goes first since it is a smaller expression than `/**`
- You need to configure your front end to support CSRF since Spring Security expects CSRF tokens by default for any `POST` request
- Permitting `/error` is important at least while debugging your login setup since otherwise any errors will get swallowed behind the authentication wall

You can find the complete code [in this sample](https://github.com/jzheaux/spring-security-examples/tree/master/two-login-pages).